# Big Cartel Luna Theme. Cart will not proceed to checkout

Tags: layout, cart, bigcartel

I'd love some help with this.

On the Cart page, when the "use my stores Layout" is selected, when customers click "Check Out", it just keeps cycling on the page and won't proceed to checkout. This is a known issue with the Luna theme for Bigcartel.

The solution I found says you need to uncheck it, but when you do, you get the error message:

```
"You must include {{ head_content }} inside the <head> tag of your content"
```

This means there's no page formatting in the code. I'm not big on the code, though I've tried for a bit to get this to work, stealing code for other pages in the theme, and failed. (it's been years since I've messed with code, so any help would be a big one).

Thank you

Here's the code for the page:

```
    <header class="product_header page_header">
  <h1>Cart</h1>
  <span class="dash"></span>
</header>

{% if cart.items != blank %}
<form id="cart-form" {% unless cart.shipping.enabled or cart.discount.enabled     %}class="no_options"{% endunless %} method="post" action="/cart" accept-charset="utf8">
  <input type="hidden" name="utf8" value='âœ“'>
  <div id="cart_description">
    <section id="cart_items">
  <ul>
    {% for item in cart.items %}
    <li class="cart_item {% unless item.product.has_default_option %}with_option{% endunless %}" id="item-{{ item.id }}">
      <div class="item_image"><img src="{{ item.product.image | product_image_url: "thumb" }}" alt="Photo of {{ item.name }}"></div>
      <dl>
        <dt><a href="{{ item.product.url }}">{{ item.product.name }}</a></dt>
        <dd class="item_price">{{ item.unit_price | money_with_sign }}{% if item.quantity > 1 %}<span class="item_quantity">(x{{ item.quantity }})</span>{% endif %}</dd>
        <dd class="quantity_input">{{ item | item_quantity_input }}</dd>
        {% unless item.product.has_default_option %}<dd class="item_option">{{ item.option.name }}</dd>{% endunless %}
      </dl>
      <a href="#" class="remove_item" title="Remove item from cart">Remove item</a>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</section>

{% if cart.shipping.enabled or cart.discount.enabled %}
<section id="cart_options">
  <ul>
    {% if cart.shipping.enabled %}
    {% if cart.shipping.strict %}
    <li id="shipping_option">
      <label for="country">Shipping</label>
      {{ store.country | country_select }}

      {% if cart.shipping.pending %}
        {% if cart.country %}
        <span class="no_shipping">We don't ship to {{ cart.country.name }}</span>
        {% endif %}
      {% endif %}
    </li>
    {% endif %}
    {% endif %}

    {% if cart.discount.enabled %}
    <li id="cart_discount" class="cart_item">
      {% if cart.discount.pending %}
        <label id="cart_discount_label" for="cart_discount_code">Discount</label>
        {{ cart.discount | discount_code_input }}
      {% elsif cart.discount.free_shipping %}
         <label for="cart_discount_code">Discount</label>
        <p>{{ cart.discount.name }}</p>
      {% else %}
        <label for="cart_discount_code">Discount</label>
        <p>{{ cart.discount.name }}</p>
      {% endif %}
    </li>
    {% endif %}
  </ul>

  <div class="cart-update">
    <button id="update-btn-footer" class="update-btn button disabled" name="update" type="submit" title="Update your cart total"><span>Update total</span></button>
  </div>
</section>
{% else %}
<section id="cart_options" class="solo_update">
  <div class="cart-update">
    <button id="update-btn-footer" class="update-btn button disabled" name="update" type="submit" title="Update your cart total"><span>Update total</span></button>
  </div>
</section>
{% endif %}
  </div>

  <section id="cart_summary">
<ul>
  <li>
    <h3>Items</h3>
    <span>{{ cart.subtotal | money_with_sign }}</span>
  </li>
  {% if cart.shipping.enabled %}
  <li id="cart-shipping-tax">
    <h3>Shipping</h3>
    {% if cart.shipping.pending %}
      {% if cart.country %}
      <span class="shipping-amount">Select another country</span>
      {% else %}
      <span class="shipping-amount">Select country</span>
      {% endif %}
    {% else %}
      <span class="shipping-amount">{{ cart.shipping.amount | money_with_sign }}</span>
    {% endif %}
  </li>
  {% else %}
  <li id="cart-shipping-tax" class="not_set">
    <h3>Shipping</h3>
    <span>Applicable fees apply</span>
  </li>
  {% endif %}

  {% if cart.discount.enabled %}
    {% if cart.discount.pending %}

    {% elsif cart.discount.free_shipping %}
    <li>
      <h3>Discount</h3>
      <span>Free shipping!</span>
    </li>
    {% else %}
    <li>
      <h3>Discount</h3>
      <span>-{{ cart.discount.amount | money_with_sign }}</span>
    </li>
    {% endif %}
  {% endif %}
  <li id="cart_total">
    <h3>Total</h3>
    <h2>{{ cart.total | money_with_sign }}</h2>
  </li>
</ul>

<button id="checkout-btn" class="button" type="submit" title="Checkout">Checkout</button>
  </section>
</form>
{% else %}
<div id="cart_empty">
  <p>Your cart is empty! Sounds like a good time to <a href="/">start shopping</a>.</p>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's not any known issues with the Luna theme code that prevents customers from being able to check out - you shouldn't need to edit any settings or change any code.

It sounds like your custom domain might be setup incorrectly with an IFRAME though, as this is known to cause problems with the cart page redirecting to the checkout. You can test this by using your storename.bigcartel.com URL vs. the custom domain to see if this is the case.

Since this isn't related specifically to your theme, you'll want to get in touch with Big Cartel support directly and they should be able to help troubleshoot further.

Comment: I found a few places that said the theme will not allow the checkout to function if "use my stores layout" is checked on the cart page.

Comment: Here is one reference to the issue from http://support.themefiend.com/customer/portal/articles/1386672-cart-checkout-common-issues-solutions

Comment: Did not uncheck the checkbox "use my store's layout" for 'Checkout' edit page. If upon clicking the 'Checkout' button in your shop, you get redirected and stuck on a page that says something like  'One moment...', this may be due to not unchecking the checkbox next to the text "use my store's layout" in the 'Checkout' edit page. This box must be unchecked in order for the checkout function to work.

Comment: Some shop owners may decide to check this box in order to have the 'One moment...' message appear within the shop's layout. However, our themes do not allow for the ability to show that message in the layout without causing issues to the checkout function.

Comment: That help article only applies to custom themes purchased from Theme Fiend, not any of the default Big Cartel themes. You'll want to work with the Big Cartel support team to resolve your particular issues, as it sounds like it's related to your custom domain.